# Allow function to accept certain type of argument?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have below methods with takes certain arguments

```
interface Kit {
    fun observe(experimentsVariable: ExperimentVariable): Observable<String>

    fun get(experimentsVariable: ExperimentVariable): String
}
```

Along with this I have defined a file which has some constants

```
object Registry {
    val SOME_KEY = ExperimentVariable.Builder<Boolean>()
        .setKey("some_key")
        .setEnabled(true)
        .setDefaultValue(false)
        .setSource("remote")
        .build()


    val SOME_KEY_1 = ExperimentVariable.Builder<String>()
        .setKey("some_key")
        .setEnabled(true)
        .setDefaultValue("some_string")
        .setSource("remote")
        .build()

    .....
}
```

Here the `build` function returns instance of `ExperimentVariable`.

Now if some class tries to call `kit.observe(Registry.SOME_KEY)` this should be allowed. But if the call is like this `kit.observe(AnotherRegistry.Another_Key)`, it should result in compile-time error or warning.

Basically I want to write my `observe` function such that it will only accept arguments of `Registry` type & nothing else.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Is `ExperimentVariable` used for anything else, or can you define the class and the way it works to tailor it specifically only for Registry and Kit?

Comment: Yes, it is used by many classes & modules

Comment: You will have to modify the `ExperimentVariable` design significantly to make this possible.

Comment: @Shrikant What does this have to do with Java?